# Looping through an array gives back different SQL results, depending on the code

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, foreach

I am turning the (key,value) into a PDO select search, but I have found a weird behavior.

This works:

```
$statement = $this->handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE pid=:pid AND section=:section");
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    $statement->bindParam(":$key", $data[$key]);

$statement->execute();
debug($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

But when I change the function inside the loop to this, it does **NOT** work

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    $statement->bindParam(":$key", $value);
```

Even though `$value == $data[$key]` is true, they second code doesnt give me the right results back. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you are binding the parameter to `$value`, which constantly changes.

If you do:

```
$value = 5;
$statement->bindParam(":$key", $value);
$value = 10;
```

Then `10` will be sent in the query.

Instead what you want to do is bind the VALUE instead of the parameter:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    $statement->bindValue(":$key", $value);
```

Comment: Damn, and I was so close.  I remembered that bindParam binds by reference, instead of value, but I couldn't figure out what needed to be said.

Comment: @Daedalus you've likely beat me to a few answers too! :P

Comment: You guys are both awesome